# Categorize chars using dictionaries in R

Tags: r

I want to categorize products in a basket using dictionaries with all the product sorts of a category. I want to check in particular if a product from my basket is an element of my dictionary, and if this is true I would like to replace the product with the name of the category (dictionary).

I imported my dictionary in a list in csv and tried to compare the products of my basket with %in% but this didn't work.

BD19jfiles[[i]]$product$name return the products of a basket.
Pistolets is a list with chars (the dictionary).

```
l <- length(BD19jfiles)
for(i in 1:l) {
if(BD19jfiles[[i]]$product$name %in% Pistolets){
grepl('Pistolet', BD19jfiles[[i]]$product$name)
}
}
```

I would like to replace the products who return true for 'BD19jfiles[[i]]$product$name %in% Pistolets' with the word 'Pistolet'

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: So I want to check for e.g. BD19jfiles[[1]]$product$name = [1] "PISTOLET WIT"    "PISTOLET TIJGER" "PISTOLET KEIZER" if those are elements of my dictionary. Suppose that my dictionary is a list with: 
1                                Pistolet wit
2                                Pistolet keizer
3                               Tijgerpistolet
4                                Pistolet tijger
5                     Pistolet met maanzaadjes
6                Pistolet met gemengde zaadjes

If they are elements from my dictionary I would like to replace them with 'Pistolet'

Comment: @handep you are experiencing problems with each of the current answers. FYI, this is the reason for requesting reproducible input and output. Having done so would have prevented this type of confusion by allowing people to verify their solution works correctly and without errors.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan I am new to programming so sorry for the confusion. I will try prevent this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list`, and update the 'name' element by checking for 'PISTOLET' substring in that element with `grepl` and assign those to "Pistolet"

```
lapply(BD19jfiles, function(x) {
   x$product$name[grepl("PISTOLET", x$product$name)] <- "Pistolet"
    x
    })
```

---

If the dictionary identifier is Pistolets

```
lapply(BD19jfiles, function(x) {
     x$product$name[x$product$name %in% Pistolets] <- "Pistolet"
     x
     })
```

If it is a substring, use `grepl`

```
nm1 <- paste0("\\b(", paste(unlist(Pistolets), collapse="|"), ")\\b")
out <- lapply(BD19jfiles, function(x) {

       x$product$name[grepl(nm1, x$product$name)] <- "Pistolet" 
       x
        })
```

Comment: This works, but only for the word "PISTOLET". I would like to compare with words from my dictionary and not only "PISTOLET". 

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: @handep What is the dicitionary identifier?  Should all of them be changed to `PISTOLET` ?

Comment: The identifier is Pistolets, this is a list of chars. And yes all of them should be changed to "Pistolet".

Comment: @handep I upddated the post.  Please check it

Comment: this processed and didn't gave any errors but it didn't replace the product$name with "Pistolet".

Comment: @handep can you check the input `Pistolets' whether it matches with name values.  If it is a substring, use `grepl`

Comment: I checked it and the name values occur in the list `Pistolets`. It is not a substring because the exact values are in the dictionary, it just doesn't seem to replace them.

Comment: @handep In that case, you may need to assisgn the output back to `BD19jfiles <-`

Comment: If I use the updated post I get the following error `Error in grepl(nm1, x$product$name) : 
  invalid regular expression '\b(c("Pistolet wit", "Pistolet grof", "Vloerpistolet", "Tijgerpistolet", "Pistolet met ... `

Comment: @handep You need to `unlist`, i thought it as a vector.  `nm1 <- paste0("\\b(", paste(unlist(Pistolets), collapse="|"), ")\\b")`

Comment: Ok, this worked with `unlist`! Thanks, you're a hero!

Answer (score 1):

```
lapply(BD19jfiles, function(x){
   x$product$name=gsub(paste(Pistolets,collapse="|"),"Pistolets",x$product$name)
   x
}
```

Here you are changing words that match any of the words in your dictionary to `Pistolet`.

Comment: If I run this code, I get the following error:  Error in gsub(paste(Pistolets, collapse = "|"), "Pistolets", x$product$name) : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file '../../../../../R-3.6.0/src/extra/tre/tre-compile.c', line 634 . 

Thanks for your help

Comment: could you give a sample of your data? like `dput(head(product))` so I can know what is not working ..

Comment: list(c("PISTOLET WIT", "PISTOLET TIJGER", "PISTOLET KEIZER"), 
    c("FRANGIPANNE", "ONTBIJTSATE")) --> this is an example of a basket with products. 

structure(list(name = c("Pistolet wit", "Pistolet grof", "Vloerpistolet", 
"Pistolet Tijger", "Pistolet met sesamzaadjes", "Pistolet met maanzaadjes"
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") --> this is a part of the dictionary